# Able to use CreateRegion in windows azure shared caching

Tags: caching, azure, azure-caching, shared-cache

I am using windows azure caching perview and i am using the windows azure shared caching in it.

With different cache service and not In-Role cache.

Though the following link says we cannot use the Regions in shared caching.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh914155.aspx

But for me its working fine.

Note: I am only using regions and not tags.

So is it correct or i am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 different ways using a cache in Azure:

- Cache service (which you're using and is in preview)
- In role caching (which that article is mostly about)
- Shared Cache

Shared Cache was Microsoft's first attempt at cache on Azure and it doesn't support all of the features the other two do.  This is what is being referred to in the article.  Shared Cache is now deprecated.